# In C, How can I use an array of strings as a lookup table?

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm so stuck. I'm learning `C` and have this question:

How can I use an array of strings as a lookup table?

I have a list of 'keys:

```
"A", "A#", "B", "Bb", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"
```

And each will refer to a specific int 'value' (which isn't unique). 
e.g. `"A" -> 9`, `"A#" -> 10`, `"Bb" -> 10`

I found an answer ([store known key/value pairs in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731939/store-known-key-value-pairs-in-c)) that I think is pointing me in the right direction when it says "I would...recommend just using an array of strings as a lookup table"

BUT I don't know how to actually implement an array of strings as a lookup table?

Comment: To put it in perspective. The full blown solution would be a hash table. Why? You have a single hash operation that computes a "key" for each of your keys and then stores the values such that your lookup is simply a `table[hashed key]`. This is highly efficient compared to a potential `strcmp` of all elements each time you want to perform a lookup -- but it is also much more complex to code correctly. For "learning", a simple array of pointers to string and an associated values array is fine. (here with 2-char keys, you can actually just compare `key[0][0]` and `key[0][1]`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  You are right. Hash approach is simple and fast. I have a simple hash operation that computes a `hashed key` =  `index` and then the lookup is simply a `value[hashed key]`. For the OP I tailored and simplified the algorithm for his keys domain.

Answer (score 5):

Since you intend to use the strings as keys with integer values, it's best to use a `struct` to contain such a pair. Then build a table of them. Finally, since you've been careful to keep the keys in sorted order, you can use the C library function `bsearch` for lookups:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct pair {
  char *key;
  int value;
} PAIR;

// Key strings must be in strcmp() sorted order!
PAIR table[] = {
  {"A",  9}, {"A#", 10}, {"B",  11}, {"Bb", 10}, {"C", 11}, {"C#", 12}, {"D", 13},
  {"D#", 14}, {"E", 15}, {"F", 16}, {"F#", 17}, {"G", 18}, {"G#", 19},
};

static int compare_keys(const void *va, const void *vb) {
  const PAIR *a = va, *b = vb;
  return strcmp(a->key, b->key);
}

int get_value(char *key) {
  PAIR key_pair[1] = {{key}};
  PAIR *pair = bsearch(key_pair, table,
      sizeof table / sizeof table[0], sizeof table[0], compare_keys);
  return pair ? pair->value : -1;
}

int main(void) {
  // Partial test: verify we can look up all the valid keys.
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof table / sizeof table[0]; ++i) {
    int value = get_value(table[i].key);
    printf("%s -> %d\n", table[i].key, value);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Short and generic.

Comment: Really appreciate your response, thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest way, you can just keep two parallel arrays of values to help map a string to an integer, like so:

```
const char *keys[13];
int keytoindex[13];

/* build table */
keys[0] = "A";
keys[1] = "A#";
/* etc. */

keytoindex[0] = 9; /* Value for 'A' */
keytoindex[1] = 10;
/* etc. */

/* later */
char *userInput = ...; /* somehow get input */
int keyvalue = -1; /* I assume -1 is not in the value array, so it can be an error condition that we didn't find that key when searching in the first array */
for( int i = 0; i < 13; i++ ) {
     if(strcmp(userInput,keys[i]) == 0 )) {
          keyvalue = keytoindex[i];
          break;
     }
}

if(keyvalue == -1) exit(1); /* send an error */
/* otherwise, keep going */
```

Naturally, this code can be re-written such that the parallel arrays are dynamically allocated, which would allow you to adjust their size during run-time. But the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning C [...]
>   how to actually implement an array of strings as a lookup table?

Two solutions are presented.

First solution is fulfilling OP's criteria (simple for the `C` beginner and has indexed `lookup table`).
The solution comes from the analyses of the domain: the nature of the keys. 
After proper arrangement of the keys in the `str_key` table, the process of the deriving corresponding index to the `lookup table` is very simple.
No intensive computation is needed. No `strcmp` or other search function is used.

I truly believe that this is the shortest, simplest and the fastest solution for the presented problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
// int index   =  { 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,   7,  8,   9,   10,  11,  12, 13,  14  };
int value[]    =  { 9, 10, 11, 13, 17, 19,  7,  10, 10,  12,   15,  -1,  20,  8,   0  }; 

char *str_key[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","A#","Bb","C#","D#","Eb","F#","G#",NULL};

int get_value(char *key, int v[])      // magic happens here!
{
    // From string key we build corresponding index to the `value` array
                                      // Note: index for key "A" == 0  
    int index = (int) (key[0] - 'A'); // One letter key will have index from 0 to 6

    if( key[1] !=0 )                  // two letter key have his index from 7 to 13   
    {
        index = index + 7;            // index for "A#" == 7
    }

    if( (index < 0) || (index > 13) ) // protection from bad keys
        return -1;  

    return v[index];                  // return the value
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; str_key[i] != NULL; i++) {

        int v = get_value( str_key[i], value);

        printf("%2s -> %2d\n", str_key[i], v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
 A ->  9                                                                                                                                        
 B -> 10                                                                                                                                        
 C -> 11                                                                                                                                        
 D -> 13                                                                                                                                        
 E -> 17                                                                                                                                        
 F -> 19                                                                                                                                        
 G ->  7                                                                                                                                        
A# -> 10                                                                                                                                        
Bb -> 10                                                                                                                                        
C# -> 12                                                                                                                                        
D# -> 15                                                                                                                                        
Eb -> -1                                                                                                                                        
F# -> 20                                                                                                                                        
G# ->  8
```

Second simple solution:

Second solution does not use lookup table but is also easy to implement, flexible  and easy to understand.

It is based on the fact that

- set of keys is small
- keys are maximum `2` characters long.

The solution is very fast. It avoids `strcmp` or any other searching function. The particular key is build from the string in very simple fashion.

The solution is based on **multi-character constant**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax)

> Multi-character constants (e.g. 'xy') are valid, although rarely
>   used — they let one store several characters in an integer (e.g. 4
>   ASCII characters can fit in a 32-bit integer, 8 in a 64-bit one).

[6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.4.4.html):
An integer character constant is a sequence of `one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes`, as in `'x'`.

The code should compile without warning under `gcc` with`-Wall`, and a “`multi-character character constant”` warning with `-pedantic`.
You can disable the warning with `-Wno-multichar`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *str_key[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","A#","Bb","C#","D#","Eb","F#","G#",NULL};

int build_index (char *key)
{
 // The magic happens here:
 // We take the string eg. "A#" 
 // and we construct corresponding multi-character constant 'A#'
 //                 A                  # 
    int index;

    if( key[1] == 0 )
        index = (int) key[0]; 
    else
        index = (int) ( (key[0] << 8) | key[1] );

    return index;   
}

int get_value (int key)
{
  switch (key)
    {
    case 'A':   return 9;
    case 'A#':  return 10;
    case 'B':   return 10;
    case 'Bb':  return 10;
    case 'C':   return 11;
    case 'C#':  return 12;
    case 'D':   return 13;
    case 'D#':  return 15;
    case 'E':   return 17;        
    case 'F':   return 19;
    case 'F#':  return 20;
    case 'G':   return 7;          
    case 'G#':  return 8;      
    deafult:
      break;
    }
  return -1;
}

int main (void)
{
    for (int i = 0; str_key[i] != NULL; i++) {

        int v = get_value( build_index( str_key[i] ) );

        printf("%2s -> %2d\n", str_key[i], v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
 A ->  9                                                                                                              
 B -> 10                                                                                                              
 C -> 11                                                                                                              
 D -> 13                                                                                                              
 E -> 17                                                                                                              
 F -> 19                                                                                                              
 G ->  7                                                                                                              
A# -> 10                                                                                                              
Bb -> 10                                                                                                              
C# -> 12                                                                                                              
D# -> 15                                                                                                              
Eb -> -1                                                                                          
F# -> 20                                                                                
G# ->  8
```

Look over the solutions and let me know if you have further questions. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of learning you can pack into this exercise. An optimal solution, short of a hash table, would be to use a `stuct` to form the pairs as Gene has shown in his answer. Any time you need to coordinate unrelated values of differing types, you should think `struct`.

However, based on your question, it is unclear whether you are able to use a `struct` for your solution. If not, then a beginning way to associate values of differing types would be the simple use of two arrays where the key/value association is provided by *array index*.

As mentioned in my comment to your question, you can easily map your keys into an *array of pointers*, e.g.:

```
    char *arr[] = { "A", "A#", "B", "Bb", "C", "C#", "D", /* array of pointers */
                    "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#" };
```

You can then hold your values in a separate integer array with the same number of elements where the index for key `"A"` (e.g. `0`) corresponds to its associated value in your values array (e.g. `values[0] = 10;`). That provides a simple mapping of `"A"` to `10`.

Then given your array of pointers and a `'key'` you can then loop over your array attempting to match `key` against each string. When a match is found at `index`, your associated key is `values[index];`.

Putting that together in a simple function that loops over each of `'n'` strings in your array of pointers (`s` below) to locate the provided `key` and returns the index on success, or `-1` if key-not-found, you could do something like the following:

```
/* locate index in 's' associated with 'key'.
 * for 'n' keys in 's' return 'index' of matching 'key',
 * otherwise return -1 if key not found.
 */ 
int getvalue (char **s, char *key, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* loop over all keys */
        int found = 1;                      /* flag for key found */
        for (int j = 0; key[j]; j++) {      /* loop over all chars in key */
            if (key[j] != s[i][j]) {        /* if key doesn't match s[i] */
                found = 0;                  /* set not found, break */
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)          /* if all chars in key match s[i] */
            return i;       /* return index of matching key */
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(**note:** you can replace the inner-loop with `strcmp`, but without knowing whether you have the functions in `sting.h` available, a simple looping over the characters in `key` works every time. However, if you do have `string.h` available, then `strcmp` would be much better than rolling your own. You could even use `strncmp (key, s[i], KEYSIZE)` to limit the comparison in a large buffer to just the characters of interest)

Putting all the pieces together in a short example that simply randomly assigns values to each of the keys in the range of the number of `0 -> No. keys - 1`, and takes input having the user enter a key to get the associated value until `"quit"` is entered or the user cancels input with a manually generated `EOF` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze - if legacy mode enabled), you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { KEYSZ = 2, BUFSZ = 256 };    /* if you need a constant, define it */

/* simply print of all mappings */
void prnmapping (char **s, int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  %-2s : %2d\n", s[i], a[i]);
}

/* locate index in 's' associated with 'key'.
 * for 'n' keys in 's' return 'index' of matching 'key',
 * otherwise return -1 if key not found.
 */ 
int getvalue (char **s, char *key, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* loop over all keys */
        int found = 1;                      /* flag for key found */
        for (int j = 0; key[j]; j++) {      /* loop over all chars in key */
            if (key[j] != s[i][j]) {        /* if key doesn't match s[i] */
                found = 0;                  /* set not found, break */
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)          /* if all chars in key match s[i] */
            return i;       /* return index of matching key */
    }
    return -1;
}

int main (void) {

    char *arr[] = { "A", "A#", "B", "Bb", "C", "C#", "D", /*array of pointers*/
                    "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#" };
    int nelem = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr,           /* number of elements */
        values[nelem];                              /* VLA for values */

    srand (time (NULL));                /* initialize random seed */

    for (int i = 0; i < nelem; i++)     /* initialize values array */
        values[i] = rand() % nelem;

    printf ("initial string mappings:\n");  /* just dump initial mappings */
    prnmapping (arr, values, nelem);
    putchar ('\n');

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually prompting for key input until 'quit' */
        char buf[BUFSZ] = "",       /* buffer for line */
            key[KEYSZ + 1] = "";    /* buffer for key (can just use buf) */
        int index = 0;              /* int to hold index matching key */
        size_t len = 0;             /* length of input string */
        printf ("enter key ('quit' to exit): ");    /* prompt */
        if (fgets (buf, BUFSZ, stdin) == NULL) {    /* catch manual EOF */
            printf ("user canceled input.\n");
            break;
        }
        if ((len = strlen (buf)) <= 1) {    /* continue if empty line */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (buf[len - 1] == '\n')   /* check buf for trailing '\n' */
            buf[--len] = 0;         /* overwrite with nul-terminating char */
        else {  /* otherwise input equals or exceeds buffer length */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: input exceeds %d chars.\n", BUFSZ - 2);
            break;
        }
        if (strcmp (buf, "quit") == 0)  /* compare for 'quit' */
            break;
        strncpy (key, buf, KEYSZ);  /* copy KEYSZ chars from buf to key */
        key[len] = 0;  /* nul-terminate key (already done by initialization) */
        if ((index = getvalue (arr, key, nelem)) == -1) /* key not found */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: key not found.\n");
        else    /* success - key found, output associated value */
            printf ("  key: '%s'  -  value: %d\n", key, values[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(*note:* reasonable error handling is provided. Regardless of which manner you use to take user-input (though your are encouraged to use `fgets` or POSIX `getline` over `scanf` due to numerous pitfalls in `scanf`), you must validate all input. That means checking the return of whatever input function you use -- at a minimum, and handling the user canceling input by generating an `EOF`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_map_values
initial string mappings:
  A  :  4
  A# :  4
  B  :  1
  Bb :  7
  C  :  1
  C# : 11
  D  :  8
  D# :  3
  E  :  4
  F  :  2
  F# :  6
  G  :  8
  G# : 10

enter key ('quit' to exit): A
  key: 'A'  -  value: 4
enter key ('quit' to exit): A#
  key: 'A#'  -  value: 4
enter key ('quit' to exit): D
  key: 'D'  -  value: 8
enter key ('quit' to exit): D#
  key: 'D#'  -  value: 3
enter key ('quit' to exit): G#
  key: 'G#'  -  value: 10
enter key ('quit' to exit): g@
error: key not found.
enter key ('quit' to exit): B
  key: 'B'  -  value: 1
enter key ('quit' to exit): quit
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. As I said at the beginning, you can pack a lot of learning into this exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so helpful

Comment: Good, I am glad to help. Once you see it put together, it helps a lot of the lose ends fall into place. Good luck with your coding.